# Pytest coverage.py errror

Tags: python, pytest, coverage.py, pytest-cov

I unit testing python code and running command `pytest --cov`, test is running fine but coverage is not getting displayed and error is

```
INTERNALERROR>raise CoverageException("Couldn't use data file {!r}:{}".format(self.filename, msg))
INTERNALERROR> coverage.misc.CoverageException: Couldn't use data file'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Pytest\\.coverage': Safety level may not be changed inside a transaction
```

Need help with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This has been [mentioned a few times in the coverage.py issues](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues?q=is%3Aissue+safety+level+is%3Aclosed+sort%3Aupdated-desc), and the eventual discovery was that [it's a bug in Python 3.6.0](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/703#issuecomment-575628293), but if you use 3.6.1 or later, you will be fine.

If that doesn't cover your case, feel free to open an issue with details of how to reproduce.

Comment: After upgrade python `3.6.0` to `3.6.8` and re-run coverage, then it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/883#issuecomment-650562896 if you're using multiple pytests in parallel, in which case specifying a distinct coverage file for each run fixes it, like:

```
export COVERAGE_FILE=.coverage.SOMETHING_SPECIFIC_FOR_EACH_RUN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use coverage==6.3.1

This works for me

Link to certain version https://pypi.org/project/coverage/6.3.1/